# Compress/Encode Node.js Object/JSON String For Inserting into PostgreSQL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, postgresql, msgpack

Is it possible to compress/encode a Javascript object, such as

```
{
    '123.12': 10.2,
    '123.23': 11.3,
    '123.241': 9.38    
}
```

so that it takes up lesser storage space when inserted into a PostgreSQL table, possibly in a [`bytea` field](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-binary.html) if needed?

For the current purpose, it is acceptable to give up read/write speed for better storage efficiency. Also, the JSON object keys are almost always different for each rows.

Stumbled across algorithms like [MsgPack](https://msgpack.org) and wonder if it can be helpful here. Prefer this to be done on client side than on PostgreSQL, unless there is good performance/usability benefits by doing it on the database.

---

Example Node.js code that inserts a representative object `record` into PostgreSQL using Knex.js. `record.data` is the value that needs to be compressed.

```
const record = {
    firstname: 'jack',
    lastname: 'ryan',
    data: JSON.stringify({    // <--- how can we compress this string/dictionary/object?
        '123.12': 10.2,
        '123.23': 11.3,
        '123.241': 9.38    
    })
}

knex('myTable').insert(record);
```

Comment: check out http://bsonspec.org/

Comment: JSON objects large than about 2 KB [will be automatically compressed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html).